# IntelliJ Idea for non-Java development

Tags: ide, performance-tuning, intellij-idea

I want to use IntelliJ IDEA for its support of numerous languages **other than Java** (I can't imagine that I'll ever be doing Java at my current job -- and if I had to, I would just backup settings).

I would like it to be more snappy at the expense of its Java features. Are there any plugins or other facilities I can safely deactivate, gaining performance?

*The things I will **have** to do are*

- *HTML, SASS/CSS and JS for the browser*
- *JavaScript with node.js*
- *Python*
- *Erlang*
- *C and C++, when they become available (Makefiles, too)*

*There's plugins for all of these.*

Share your tunings with me!

Just that it's clear: I know that you need Java to run IntelliJ, as it is a Java program. I also know that I can set options in `vmoptions`. I am more concerned with the Java editing facilities I will probably never use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just un-tick all plugins but the ones you aren't gonna need. Go to settings, type "plugins" and deselect all, than just pick those you're gonna use.

If you don't need Java, I think it's safe to un-tick:

- **UI Designer** (for swing)
- **GWT Support**
- **Vaadin** (a GWT framework)
- Anything that starts with **Java EE**
- **JavaFX**
- **JSP**
- **Android Designer**
- **Android Support**
- **AspectJ Support** (if you have it installed)
- **Cucumber For Java**
- **Cucumber For Groovy**
- **Groovy**
- **I18N For Java**
  **J2ME**
- **JSR45 Integration**
- **JUnit**
- **Maven Integration**
- **Maven Integration Extension**
- **Persistence Frameworks Support** (used by JPA)
- Any of the **Struts** versions
- Anything that starts with **Spring**
- **TestNG-J**
- **Velocity Support**

There may be more if you installed additional plugins, but that should cover the basics<sup>★</sup>.

---

<sup>★</sup> This refers to 13.* versions.

Comment: if you can complete the list that's just good for java and useless for everything else, I will accept. How's that sound? Also, are there other tuning possibilities?